Are squatters rights real?
The term squatters rights traditionally refers to various forms of "adverse possession" which I know in most jurisdictions is a real thing, however the recent media focus on it seems to conflate them with tenants rights.
I saw an interview with one sheriff in florida talking about the recent HB 621 bill saying it's actually redundant because the "squatters" it targets are merely trespassers, and never had a real claim to any rights of a tenant, but that the police are generally unwilling to act on it because they aren't sure of the laws themselves and/or the squatter will make claims of being a tenant.
I know this question will vary a lot depending on location but I am interested in any jurisdictions really.
TL:DR question:
Assuming the person has never been a tenant or invited guest in the house, and has not met the criteria for adverse possession, do they have any sort of rights that would prevent them from simply being trespassed from the property?

https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=squatters

@BlueDogRanch thanks, I read through quite a few of those, is there one in particular you think answers my question?  So far I haven't seen one.

There are basically two kinds of squatters rights.
First, and most commonly, some squatters under some jurisdictions' laws have to be evicted just like a tenant who hasn't paid their rent, a process that can take weeks to a few months.
Second, if one possesses real estate for many years (the exact duration and conditions vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction but typically 7-21 years), one ceases to be a squatter and become the owner of the property.

Your second paragraph is referring to the mechanism of adverse possession right? It should clarify that the land needs to be possessed without permission of the owner.

@uberhaxed I left it vague "conditions vary from jurisdiction to jurisdiction" because the exact formula varies quite a bit and there are often multiple paths. Some jurisdictions require possession with a good faith belief in ownership, most require that possession be open, notorious, and hostile (i.e. without permission), but some allow sooner possession, e.g., with seven years of property tax payment and color of title. Most don't allow adverse possession against the government. The details are involved and complex in many cases.

Right, I was just pointing out that an agreement that someone can live in your house for 20 years rent free is not one of these cases, as may be implied from the broad statement.

@uberhaxed Absolute. Tenants (even tenants whose leases expire) almost never prevail in a lawsuit for adverse possession.
